# Convergence problem

Tags: measure-theory

Assume that $f_n:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is a sequence of diffeomorphism that converges to a homeomorphism $f$ so that $$\int_0^1 \left[f'_n(x)+1/f'_n(x)\right]^2 dx<M.$$ Can we state that $f'_n$ converges up  to a subsequence to $f'$ almost everywhere.

Comment: $f$ need not be differentiable everywhere under these assumptions.